# How to retrieve Image Unique Id on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, metadata

I am able to extract 'Image Unique Id' metadata from [www.get-metadata.com](http://www.get-metadata.com)

[metadata screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCOwt.png)

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg01Z.jpg) I tried to extract the non-standard field from.

I tried to get metadata using this approach on iOS.

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)imageData, nil);
NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil));
```

But it doesn't contain above property.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to get EXIF data from the image.  Here's some Playground code that does this:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let url:NSURL = URL(string:"https://mobilesecurity.win/samples/EXIF_example.jpg")! as NSURL
let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)!
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as! [String:Any]
for (key, value) in imageProperties {
    print("\(key) = \(value)")
}
```

In my sample image above, here's the result:

```
PixelHeight = 3024
{Exif} = {
    ApertureValue = "1.695993715632365";
    BrightnessValue = "7.553953257086027";
    ColorSpace = 65535;
    ComponentsConfiguration =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        0
    );
    CustomRendered = 2;
    DateTimeDigitized = "2018:05:05 16:58:33";
    DateTimeOriginal = "2018:05:05 16:58:33";
    DigitalZoomRatio = "1.212510024057739";
    ExifVersion =     (
        2,
        2,
        1
    );
    ExposureBiasValue = 0;
    ExposureMode = 0;
    ExposureProgram = 2;
    ExposureTime = "0.003355704697986577";
    FNumber = "1.8";
    Flash = 24;
    FlashPixVersion =     (
        1,
        0
    );
    FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 34;
    FocalLength = "3.99";
    ISOSpeedRatings =     (
        20
    );
    LensMake = Apple;
    LensModel = "iPhone 8 Plus back dual camera 3.99mm f/1.8";
    LensSpecification =     (
        "3.99",
        "6.6",
        "1.8",
        "2.8"
    );
    MeteringMode = 5;
    PixelXDimension = 4032;
    PixelYDimension = 3024;
    SceneCaptureType = 0;
    SceneType = 1;
    SensingMethod = 2;
    ShutterSpeedValue = "8.219041278295606";
    SubjectArea =     (
        2483,
        33,
        292,
        296
    );
    SubsecTimeDigitized = 269;
    SubsecTimeOriginal = 269;
    WhiteBalance = 0;
}
DPIWidth = 72
Depth = 8
{ExifAux} = {
    Regions =     {
        HeightAppliedTo = 3024;
        RegionList =         (
                        {
                AngleInfoRoll = 270;
                AngleInfoYaw = 270;
                ConfidenceLevel = 99;
                FaceID = 29;
                Height = "0.06024057738572575";
                Timestamp = 2147483647;
                Type = Face;
                Width = "0.07273601924233319";
                X = "0.6160769693325315";
                Y = "0.03012028869286288";
            },
                        {
                AngleInfoRoll = 270;
                AngleInfoYaw = 315;
                ConfidenceLevel = 99;
                FaceID = 30;
                Height = "0.08487570168404171";
                Timestamp = 2147483647;
                Type = Face;
                Width = "0.06303788334335536";
                X = "0.5821334936861094";
                Y = "0.2045292702485966";
            },
                        {
                AngleInfoRoll = 240;
                AngleInfoYaw = 0;
                ConfidenceLevel = 99;
                FaceID = 31;
                Height = "0.07153809141940659";
                Timestamp = 2147483647;
                Type = Face;
                Width = "0.05333974744437764";
                X = "0.4718171978352376";
                Y = "0.8029029671210907";
            }
        );
        WidthAppliedTo = 4032;
    };
}
Orientation = 6
ProfileName = Display P3
{MakerApple} = {
    1 = 9;
    10 = 2;
    12 =     (
        "7.1875",
        "31.75391"
    );
    13 = 38;
    14 = 4;
    16 = 1;
    2 = <8e021002 6c011b02 d7005f00 4402e002 54016a00 36004700 4b003e00 2e002600 a101a201 8801ab01 85005900 3a02cf02 b0005900 95007600 2e002400 2d008300 cc031d02 2101d800 79005b00 1602fe02 4702b200 bd006900 29001600 67008700 17056f02 4901a200 65006d00 60026202 02026000 55003100 3e004500 99009000 43048b01 b201cc00 7d008400 6202f201 c4019500 24022500 46005000 4f004700 3f02af01 0e01cb00 79007e00 54024e03 bb01b400 dc001900 60005500 22001600 5c014d01 6601d700 77007800 68028402 03017700 55002600 25003700 2b001800 6e019f01 4f011701 79007900 d8001501 bd003b00 6c005300 2f002f00 26002600 4902f401 69020d01 89005300 4d01e200 4c005c00 91005700 36002100 1c002c00 8b01ce01 b8014400 5d007900 8c004f00 9a007700 ad003500 29004000 2a001900 bd017c01 32013e00 36006200 7e008f00 62004100 86002400 34004800 26001b00 eb01a101 f8003b00 35003b00 ca010a01 8f007700 7b002c00 33005100 36002e00 5e017501 47013900 34003800 d901d101 7f005200 22001b00 23002000 22002a00 0501d700 b4003800 33003800 a501b300 92005300 20001800 36002500 19001600 fa012201 59003700 33003600 26016f00 cc009600 2d001400 27003100 20001900 f300a300 3f003600 33003500 2a01cc00 d200b700 3f001c00 30002400 1f002000>;
    20 = 3;
    22 = "AR1G+K438OnfHOzqQ+UT5Ix1ijDD";
    23 = 0;
    25 = 2;
    26 = q825s;
    3 =     {
        epoch = 0;
        flags = 1;
        timescale = 1000000000;
        value = 93963587977416;
    };
    31 = 0;
    4 = 1;
    5 = 178;
    6 = 175;
    7 = 1;
    8 =     (
        "-0.02829843",
        "-0.9835473",
        "-0.1944532"
    );
}
{TIFF} = {
    DateTime = "2018:05:05 16:58:33";
    Make = Apple;
    Model = "iPhone 8 Plus";
    Orientation = 6;
    ResolutionUnit = 2;
    Software = "11.3.1";
    XResolution = 72;
    YResolution = 72;
}
ColorModel = RGB
DPIHeight = 72
PixelWidth = 4032
```

The specific fields in the EXIF data are up to the producer of the image.  I don't know that 'Image Unique Id' is inherently part of an image, so its presence is dependent on the device taking the picture to add it.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're assuming that the EXIF data has a non-standard field in it.  If you post a link to an image we can check to see if/where the field in question exists.

Comment: Thanks David, I added the image link which you can check

Comment: When I load that image into the website I get this:  https://www.get-metadata.com/result/e6d55317-abd4-49a3-a918-7da2aac85f18   it does not have "Image Unique Id'" as a field.

Comment: Strange, this is what I am getting https://www.get-metadata.com/result/450f2775-6eb5-47d6-83b0-40f8d6b4680d